# Getting input tag to cover 100% of div width

Tags: css

I'm trying to write an input tag that covers 100% of the div's width and have written the following CSS:

```
input {
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: 1px solid #3EE514;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #000;
}
```

I've tried both `width` and `min-width` at 100% but neither work yet when I set a pixel value the input field will increase in size.  How do I change the CSS to cover the whole div?

Thanks

Comment: `min-width` should work with input fields. In fact, with a basic `<input>` field, your code works [perfectly as is](https://jsfiddle.net/jzs6sqa8/). There must be something else causing the problem.

Comment: You're right.  I had the fields within a table.  Dumb dumb tired

Answer (score 0):

When you say `width: 100%` its taking the parent element's width. But, if the parent doesn't have a specified width, then  it's simply taking the 100% of 0 :)

You could either set the outer `div` to have a width in pixels first, or do something like

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
}

.outerDiv, input {
    width: 100%
}
```